# ASP.NET MVC 4, Remove Primary Key from Create form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making my first mvc 4 project, database first, when I am using Scaffold to create Views and Control,

its also adding Primary Key Field in Create and Edit page.

also on index page in place of Item.ProductId its showing /* id=item.PrimaryKey */

what am I doing wrong. please help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the `placeholders`?  the `/* id=item.PrimaryKey */`, is just highlighting that you need to add your **items primary key** in place of this placeholder.  Also, in the `edit` page, when you edit your item, you need to primary key to know which record to update.

For example, if you had a table of `Products`, and your primary key was `ProductId`, then you would replace the commented out line with `id=item.ProductId`.